# Creating a new workbook for each row in an existing workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use one excel sheet that contains several rows of data and create separate workbooks for each of those rows using one of the values in the row as the new workbook name.  These workbooks will be saved as comma delimited workbooks so they can be uploaded into the controller for a piece of machinery.  I can manually open a new workbook and get the externally reference the cells from the base workbook but am confused on how to write the loop to have it automatically move through the rows and create a new workbook and how to use one of the values as the name for the new workbook.

The base workbook is structured in rows from A to J where column A contains the value I want to save the new workbook as.  The new workbook needs to transpose the values and break the row into two columns (this is due to the structure of the control program on the machine and not something I can change).  The first column in the new workbook would contain the values from B to H and the second column would contain values from I and J.

For clarification:
Base workbook row -   x   xx   xxx   xxxx   xxxxx ... X XX

New workbook format -  The small x's would be column entries in A and the capital X would be column entries in B.

I am able to do the above and convert the row to two separate columns in a new workbook.  I have also tried looking at the similar questions and responses for this but haven't been able to piece together a way to make the above work.

Can anyone give some ideas on how to approach writing the loop for the workbook?  I don't mind playing with it and trying to get it to work but admit to being over my head in getting started with automatically stepping through the rows and saving the new workbook by referencing a cell value in the base workbook.

Thanks for any help anyone is able to provide.

The code from the Macro is listed below:

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    Workbooks.Add
    Application.Left = 721
    Application.Top = 1
    Application.Width = 720
    Application.Height = 780
    Windows("TEST.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B2:H2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book10").Activate
    Range("A1:A7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("B1").Select
    Windows("B9 for Import TEST.xlsx").Activate
    Range("I2:J2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book10").Activate
    Range("B1:B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Windows("TEST.xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

It will work copy over the data once but then tells me that the subscript is out of range highlighting the ~Windows("Book10").Activate~ line.

Comment: upload what code you have tried so far. And your xxxxx clarification seems to be confusing.

Comment: Yeah I wrote the X's in a column but when I posted it just put them in a line so I edited that.

Comment: Concerning the your current code: I would avoid using .copy and .pastespecial in VBA, especially when doing more complicated things like what you need. It's much better to use direct cell references combined with For loops, as you see in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with. I ran this code with a button on work sheet with data that looks like this:[image]

Here's the code attached to button 1:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error GoTo PROC_ERROR

Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook, NewBook As Workbook
Dim ThisWorksheet As Worksheet, NewWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, ExportCount As Integer

Set ThisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ThisWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ExportCount = 0

For i = 1 To 10
    If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
        Set NewWs = NewBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For j = 2 To 8
            If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
                NewWs.Cells(j - 1, 1) = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
        For k = 9 To 10
            If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, k) <> "" Then
                NewWs.Cells(k - 8, 2) = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, k)
            End If
        Next k
        With NewBook
            .Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
            .Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
            .Title = ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 1)
            .SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        End With
        ExportCount = ExportCount + 1
    End If
Next i

PROC_ERROR:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "This macro has encountered an error and needs to exit. However, some or all of your exported workbooks may still have been saved. Please try again." _
    & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbInformation
    ExportCount = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Successfully exported " & ExportCount & " workbooks!", vbInformation
    ExportCount = 0
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Output looks like this:[image]

Let me know if you want me to explain the code in detail!

EDIT: Updated code: Added `Application.ScreenUpdating` handling, and proper Error Handling.

Comment: If you could explain the code that would be very helpful for me moving forward.  If you don't mind I would rather be sure I understand what it is doing than just copying and pasting it.

Comment: Totally! It's just using a series of "For" loops to achieve what you want. In the code "i" is going to represent a row number in you main worksheet. So when it says `For i =1 To 10`, it's basically saying "Run this loop ten times." But "i" is also a variable, so each time the For loop is run, "i" will equal one more than it did before. So the first time it runs, "i" is 1, the next time it runs "i" is 2, etc. So `ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 1)` is cell A1 if i=1, A2 if i=2, etc. (Running out of characters; see next comment)

Comment: What I'm doing is having the main part of the code repeat itself for each row, from 1 to 10, if it isn't blank (that's what `If ThisWorksheet.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then` is checking for). Then telling certain cells in the new workbook to equal certain cells in the main workbook (using smaller "For" loops).

Comment: First, I did try the code and it does exactly what I wanted so thank you for that!  Second, what you explained above makes sense and I can read through that section of the code and follow along so thank you for taking the time to answer and explain.  I have a couple more questions if you don't mind. Are the "Dim ThisWorkbook As Workbook, NewBook As Workbook" lines similar to variable declaration lines in other code?  Are you just defining them for use later on in the loops?  Next question in new comment.

Comment: Are you just using the lines I mentioned above to switch what workbook you are referencing?  That is the last thing that I'm not sure I follow in the code is how you define the old and new worksheet and switch between referencing the old and the new.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Yes, "Dim" is to declare variables in VBA. To set variables, you just use "=". So if I had `Dim x as Integer`, and wanted to set it as 5, then I would later type `x = 5`. For objects, you have to use "Set" before the variable, so `Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook`. As for "switching" between the old and the new workbooks, each "new workbook" is being edited in the background, until the `SaveAs` part of the code, at which point it opens automatically, then the code moves on to the next workbook. There's no need (at least for this purpose) to actually switch between different workbooks.

Comment: Well that explains why I didn't see the part where you were switching back and forth!  The code makes sense to me and works as needed so thank you again and for your help.